# What is a capital joke?

Tags: meaning

What is a capital joke?
It is quoted in War and Peace by Oxford World Classic  : 'But do you know, my dear, that was a capital joke.' said the count.

Comment: It's an old fashioned expression:  it means a good/excellent joke.

Comment: Just one thing to note, War and Peace was written in Russian in the mid 1860s, by Leo Tolstoy.  It was the translators Louise and Aylmer Maude who chose that phraseology, and they translated it in 1922-23. So, its typical of English at that time (specifically in England), rather than the time, place and language of the original. I've no idea what the original Russian phrase was.

Comment: @BillyKerr The original goes, "Однако, ma chère, это славная штука, — сказал граф". *Славный* in Russian is literally *famous*, but also used affectionately as *nice* or *good*.

Comment: @svavil but штука is more general than *joke*, perhaps closer to *thing*

Comment: @svavil - cool!  That explains it - use of "captial" back in the twenties was kind of informal/slang, a bit like how Americans use "awesome" today.

Comment: @Henry Interesting - I read the preceding lines, and had no idea what the "joke" they're referring to was even supposed to be.

Comment: @Henry, even more: a "joke" is «шУТка», «шТУка» is a «thing». It may be a mistranslation because of this.

Comment: @BillyKerr, "War and Peace was written in Russian" — more like Russian-French mix (about 3% of French), even in that quote "my dear" in the original is "ma chère".

Comment: Perhaps it is one that makes you laugh your head off.

Comment: That's interesting - I thought 'famous' had a similar meaning to 'capital' in that period. Perhaps 'famous' was used a little later in English?

Comment: @NuclearHoagie there's a passage where the joke is explained, "They tied a policeman and the bear back to back and put the bear into the Moyka Canal". So the count refers to this.

Comment: I see what you did there: https://www.etymonline.com/word/capital +1

Comment: @KevinMartin - capital joke, my good fellow!

Comment: I wonder if this specific wording is meant to be a play on 'capital crime'. I haven't read the book so I can't say what the context is.

Answer (score 40):

In the English of the time in which the book is set, just a very good joke.

Oxford Languages has, as its third definition of *capital* as an adjective:

DATED: INFORMAL

excellent.

"he's a really capital fellow"

Answer (score 18):

"Capital" means first rate or excellent. See, for example, https://www.thefreedictionary.com/capital, adjective definition #2.

So a "capital joke" is a very good joke. Just like a "capital idea" is a very good idea, or a "capital restaurant" is a very good restaurant.

However, this use of the word is mostly obsolete. If you want to express this idea, say "very good" or "excellent" instead.

Note that "capital" has several other definitions. Mostly it is used to mean the city where the government of a country or other political unit is located, like, "Paris is the capital of France." It can also mean resources used to produce goods, or the money used to buy those resources, like, "The company invested a lot of capital in expanding its factory".

(There might be an amusing pun somewhere about a "capital joke" being a joke about the center of government and also being a very funny joke. Not to say that I have invented such a joke.)

Comment: I just remembered a joke I heard years ago: A teacher asks a student, "What would it be called if you committed a crime and you were whipped?" The student said, "That would be corporal punishment." So the teacher said, "What if I committed a crime and I was executed?" And the student said, "Oh, that would be capital!"

Comment: a capital capital joke!

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'mostly obsolete'; it's certainly not [obsolete, or even archaic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Obsolete_and_archaic_terms#Classifications_of_old_words). Another answer notes that Oxford has it as 'dated', which I'd probably agree with, although I dare say there are social circles where it would still be in current use.

Comment: @AakashM If you're born into the British aristocracy, maybe it's a thing.  For anyone not in the aristocracy, if you're over 80 then it's "dated".  If you're not in the county set and you were born after WIII, it's archaic.  If you were born after 1980, it will not even be understood unless you've read some English literature classics at school and discovered this archaic meaning (as Mankak is currently demonstrating).

Comment: @Graham I was born a decade after 1980, and do recognize it, but primarily from Mr. Burns using it in The Simpsons. But the point of him using it is to further his characterization as implausibly old and out of touch (see also his line "I'd like to send this letter to the Prussian Consulate in Siam by aeromail. Am I too late for the 4:30 auto-gyro?").

Comment: @llama Yes, I'm an old man so I'm not so up on new trends like texting. I prefer to use a good old-fashioned email.